# How to run python script as executable and keep access to files surrounding it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, sqlite

I have a python program "Alfred.py" that I want to be able to run by clicking an icon or typing "Alfred" in the terminal. It is connected to a database file and pulls in Excel files when asked to. When I try to run it by clicking, this is what I get:

```
mcaay:~ mcaay$ /Users/mcaay/Documents/Moje\ Dokumenty/MANTA/Alfred/Alfred.desktop ; exit;
/Users/mcaay/Documents/Moje Dokumenty/MANTA/Alfred/Alfred.desktop: line 1: [Desktop: command not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mcaay/Documents/Moje Dokumenty/MANTA/Alfred/Alfred.py", line 59, in <module>
    AND Usterka IS NOT NULL;""")
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: repairs
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]
```

This line:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: repairs
```

means that Alfred.py didn't find .db file, created it but it was empty so there was no table called "repairs". This .db file sits in the same directory as Alfred.py.

What I did until now:

- added "#!/usr/bin/env python3" as the 1st line of Alfred.py
- typed "chmod +x /Users/mcaay/Documents/Moje\ Dokumenty/MANTA/Alfred/Alfred.py" in terminal to make it executable
- added "export PATH=$PATH:/Users/mcaay/Documents/Moje\ Dokumenty/MANTA/Alfred/" to my .bash_profile to make Alfred.py available from any place in terminal
- created Alfred.desktop file for a clickable icon:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Alfred
Exec=python3 /Users/mcaay/Documents/Moje\ Dokumenty/MANTA/Alfred/Alfred.py
Terminal=true
Type=Application
```

- made Alfred.desktop executable by typing "chmod +x /Users/mcaay/Documents/Moje\ Dokumenty/MANTA/Alfred/Alfred.desktop" in the terminal

When I type in terminal "Alfred.py", I get:

```
mcaay:~ mcaay$ Alfred.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mcaay/Documents/Moje Dokumenty/MANTA/Alfred/Alfred.py", line 59, in <module>
    AND Usterka IS NOT NULL;""")
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: repairs
```

So the same as with clicking "Alfred.desktop". 
If I type just "Alfred", I get:

```
mcaay:~ mcaay$ Alfred
-bash: Alfred: command not found
```

I want just typing "Alfred" to work and I want it to see the database and other files correctly, or alternatively if clicking the icon will work properly it is acceptable too. My Googe-Fu failed me here. What do?

P.S. I noticed that a database file is created in my home directory ("/Users/mcaay"), as if Alfred.py was pulled from original destination to some temporary destination and executed there (other files were not pulled so program crashed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after a good night of sleep the things I've read finally computed in my head and I got an answer. Everything I did before is unnecessary and can be discarded.

My solution (keep in mind I'm using macOS Mojave atm):

1. In home directory, I created a file called `.start_alfred.sh`.
   This is a shell script that will have a callable command in terminal to go to my specified directory and then run a python script.
2. Inside, I wrote this:

```
#!/bin/bash

function Alfred() {
    cd /Users/mcaay/Documents/Moje\ Dokumenty/MANTA/Alfred
    python3 Alfred.py
}
```

The name of this function (`Alfred`) is what will invoke the shell commands included inside. It's basically doing what you would normally do in terminal to start a program.

3. In my `.bash_profile`, I added `source ~/.start_Alfred.sh` at the end, so everytime I open the terminal everything that is in `.start_Alfred.sh` becomes available immediately.

That's basically it :) Maybe not the cleanest but super easy and good enough for what I need. Tanktalus' and asafpr's answers helped me to come up with this solution.

Use case:

```
mcaay:~ mcaay$ Alfred

Co jest?
>>> thx
np

mcaay:Alfred mcaay$
```

`Thx` is the command to end the python script.

Answer (score 0):

When you tell SQLite where to find the db, you're using a relative path, but that relative path is relative to the *current working directory*. You need to either change directory inside your script or give SQLite a full path to your db. Either way, this requires the logic for finding where your script is, or you can put the db in another well-known path (e.g., `~/.config/alfred`).  Personally, I prefer always building full paths, and avoiding relative paths (and the change-directory) option as much as possible, but a chdir to your script path should be relatively safe as well, and may require less change at this point.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense. I don't want to use full paths because many people will use this program and I don't want to tell them where they should place it on their computer.

Comment: Btw, your answer helped me to come up with a different solution, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think that it's just looking for the .db file in the directory it was executed in. You should either define a .db with the absolute path or access the .db file in the same directory of the script which you can get using:
`os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])`

Comment: Thanks, was reluctant to use `os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])` immidiately, as it would make the code a bit less readable in a potentially avoidable situation, and luckily I found a different way to do it.